# IPV4 to IPV6 migration

Tags: .net, iis, migration

I have Windows 2012 Servers running SQL Server 2019 and a hybrid.NET 4.72 & .NET Core [separately].
The application running on IIS locally in dev environment. I wish to make the changes on the application end [IIS,Framework,ASP.NET] to make it IPv6 compatible?
I do realise that I have to
Enable IPv6 on the IIS server.
Set the application pool to use IPv6.
Configure the application to listen on IPv6 addresses.
Looking for recommnedations for the below

1. How can I test the application with a variety of IPv6 clients and devices?
2. How can I simulate the network is configured to support IPv6?

Comment: This is too huge a topic to cover. I wrote some tips back in 2009 when I worked on #SNMP Library, https://halfblood.pro/crossroad-billboard-how-to-support-ip-v6-in-net-c-d579939ce0f0. I will suggest you set a virtual lab with virtual machines on IPv6 addresses, and then you can test your applications and identify gaps.

Comment: Run netsh as an administrator, then type “http”.
Enter the following command:`add iplisten ipaddress=::`
This enables IIS to listen on both IPv4 and IPv6 while leaving the setting within IIS to listen on "all interfaces". Restart IIS to apply changes.